# Create a new table in access database with Python using button

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, ms-access-2007

I am trying to make a new table in access database.
There should be two buttons.

Button 1 (Browse): select the (.mdb) file where a new table would be created

Button 2 (Run)   : create new table

The code I wrote so far:

```
import pyodbc
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

def browse():
    A = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    return str (A)

def run():
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=' + browse())
    cur = conn.cursor()

    if cur.tables(table = 'new').fetchone():
    cur.execute('DROP TABLE new')

    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE new( ID integer, Name string)')
    conn.commit()
    print (' New created')


r = Tk()
r.title ('test')
r.geometry ('200x300')

b1 = Button(r,text = 'Browse', command = browse).place (x = 10, y =10)
b2 = Button (r, text = 'run', command = run).place (x = 10, y =50)
r.mainloop()
```

The problem is when I hit run button it again ask to select the file whether run button is supposed to create a new table in the previously selected (with browse button) access database.  If anyone can show me a way.  I am using Python 2.7 and MS access 2007.

Comment: You're getting the File Open dialog again because the first line of the `run()` function calls the `browse()` function. You need to have the `browse()` function stash the value of `A` someplace where the `run()` function can retrieve it.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks.  I am wondering how to get return only the path of file so that run() function can only retrieve the path rather than whole function.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have `pyodbc` but rest of code is working.

I put it in class to make it cleaner. I change some names - `run()` to `create()` because I use name `run()` for function with `mainloop()`.

If you use `Create` button it open `FileDialog` only if you didn't select file before.

After creation of database program forget filename to be ready to select another filename directly in `Create` button

```
import pyodbc
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

class Application():

    def __init__(self, root):
        #print 'debug: __init__()'

        self.root = root

        self.root.title('Database Creator')
        self.root.geometry('300x300')

        self.b1 = Button(self.root, text='Browse', command=self.browse)
        self.b1.place(x=10, y=10)

        self.b2 = Button(self.root, text='Create', command=self.create)
        self.b2.place(x=10, y=50)

        self.filepath = None

    #----------------------

    def run(self):
        #print 'debug: run()'

        self.root.mainloop()

    #----------------------

    def browse(self):
        #print 'debug: browse()'

        self.filepath = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

        if self.filepath:
            print 'File selected:', self.filepath
        else:
            print 'File not selected'

    #----------------------

    def create(self):
        #print 'debug: create()'

        if not self.filepath:
            self.browse()

        if self.filepath:
            conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=' + self.filepath)
            cur = conn.cursor()

            if cur.tables(table = 'new').fetchone():
                cur.execute('DROP TABLE new')

            cur.execute('CREATE TABLE new( ID integer, Name string)')

            conn.commit()

            print ' New created'

            # now I will be ready to select another file
            self.filepath = None

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Application(Tk()).run()
```

Comment: Sorry :) I did not pay attention, you're not OP :)